# Printing string array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, string, mips

I want to print out an array in MIPS. This is what I did

```
.globl main
.data
    hello: .asciiz "Hello, the string is:\n"
    names:
        .align 3
        .asciiz "MIPS"
        .align 3
        .asciiz "IS"
        .align 3
        .asciiz "CRAZY"
        .align 3

.text
main:
    la $a0, hello
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #print the first member of the names array
    la $t0, names
    lw $a0, 0($t0)
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

But when I assemble and run, MARS report there is an address out of range. I doubt that what I did wrong is taking the first element out of the array. Could someone help me explain what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the address of the String that you need to print and not the string itself

```
la $t0, names
lw $a0, 0($t0)
```

instead of this write the below

```
la  $a0,names
```

This would print "MIPS IS CRAZY"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `syscall 4` requires `$a0` to be the address of the string to be displayed, but you are loading garbage to `$a0` (either 0 or the contents of the first characters of the string to be displayed).

Don't know why you are aligning the strings either.

I'd modify the code to look like this:

```
.globl main
.data
    hello: .asciiz "Hello, the string is:\n"
    names1:
        .asciiz "MIPS"
    names2:
        .asciiz "IS"
    names3:
        .asciiz "CRAZY"

.text
main:
    la $a0, hello
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #print the first member of the names array
    la $a0, names1
    syscall

    #print the second member of the names array
    la $a0, names2
    syscall

    #exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score -1):

```
li $t0,0

addi $t0,$t0,16 #->porque al usar aling va de 8 en 8 (0,8,16...)

la $a0,names($t0)
```

Comment: Please explain where this code goes in the program and how it fixes the issue. I also suggest writing comments in the code in English.